# Regex which finds all instances of a string under another specific string

Tags: regex

Im not sure if this is possible in a single Regex or if I will need two.

I have a string that looks like:

```
route-table arlrt2
 rg arlrg2
 route testroute p 1.0/24 np 10.4
 route route2 p 1.0/24 np 10.4
 route route3 p 1.0/24 np 10.4
route-table arlrt3
 rg arlrg2
 route testroute p 1.0/24 np 10.4
 route route2 p 1.0/24 np 10.4
 route route3 p 1.0/24 np 10.4
route-table arlrt3
 rg arlrg2
 route testroute p 1.0/24 np 10.4
 route route2 p 1.0/24 np 10.4
 route route3 p 1.0/24 np 10.4
```

I want to extract the route information for a specific route-table. Ideally I would have a list of routes containing for example strings like "testroute p 1.0/24 np 10.4".

I have found how to get all routes

```
  (route .*\s)
```

Or how to get a single route under the route table

```
route-table arlrt2\s.*\s*( route .*\s)
```

However I cannot seem to figure out how to find ALL the routes under the route-table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **which flavor** plus what do you mean with:  *find ALL the routes under the route-table*

Comment: Do you need something like this: [`route-table(?:.*\s*){5}$`](https://regex101.com/r/1aeM6y/2)

Comment: Or you need to **parse** all `route` under the `route-table`?

Comment: It would be in python if thats what you mean by which flavor, and it would be all the routes under a single route-table, preferably parsed into a list :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to match the **route-table** sections, something like this:

### `^route-table(?:.*\s*){5}$`

online test:

### [`^route-table(?:.*\s*){5}$`](https://regex101.com/r/1aeM6y/4)

may help you, and you should note that the matches rely on **fix-line-size**; here **{5}**. Also it treats the input as: **multi-line-mode**. Of course we can use **lazy star** `.*?` for **single-line-mode** like below:

### `^route-table(?:.*?$\s*){5}$`

test:

### [`^route-table(?:.*?$\s*){5}$`](https://regex101.com/r/1aeM6y/3)

---

**But** of you want to parse, here is a **Perl one-liner** solution and I assume you have an input that looks like this:

```
##############################
other stuff
##############################
route-table arlrt2                       // line 1
 rg arlrg2                               // line 2
 route testroute p 1.0/24 np 10.4        // line 3
 route route2 p 1.0/24 np 10.4           // line 4
 route route3 p 1.0/24 np 10.4           // line 5
##############################
other stuff
##############################
route-table arlrt3
 rg arlrg2
 route testroute p 1.0/24 np 10.4
 route route2 p 1.0/24 np 10.4
 route route3 p 1.0/24 np 10.4
##############################
other stuff
##############################
route-table arlrt3
 rg arlrg2
 route testroute p 1.0/24 np 10.4
 route route2 p 1.0/24 np 10.4
 route route3 p 1.0/24 np 10.4
##############################
other stuff
##############################
```

**Still the parse relies on `fix-line-size` and here is 5**.

Now, for accessing to these sections (=route-table(s)) we can:

```
perl -lne '$s=$.;($e=$s+5) if/route-table/g; print if $s++<$e' file
```

the output:

```
route-table arlrt2
 rg arlrg2
 route testroute p 1.0/24 np 10.4
 route route2 p 1.0/24 np 10.4
 route route3 p 1.0/24 np 10.4
route-table arlrt3
 rg arlrg2
 route testroute p 1.0/24 np 10.4
 route route2 p 1.0/24 np 10.4
 route route3 p 1.0/24 np 10.4
route-table arlrt3
 rg arlrg2
 route testroute p 1.0/24 np 10.4
 route route2 p 1.0/24 np 10.4
 route route3 p 1.0/24 np 10.4
```

then, for: *all the routes under a single route-table, preferably parsed into a list*

you simply can **push** when `!/(?:route-table|rg)`

So the:

```
perl -ne '$s=$.;($e=$s+5) if/route-table.*?$/g && ($rt=$&); push(@L,$_) if $s++<$e && !/(?:route-table|rg)/;if($s==$e){print @L;@L=()}' file
```

outputs:

```
 route testroute p 1.0/24 np 10.4 #1
 route route2 p 1.0/24 np 10.4 #1
 route route3 p 1.0/24 np 10.4 #1
 route testroute p 1.0/24 np 10.4 #2
 route route2 p 1.0/24 np 10.4 #2
 route route3 p 1.0/24 np 10.4 #2
 route testroute p 1.0/24 np 10.4 #3
 route route2 p 1.0/24 np 10.4 #3
 route route3 p 1.0/24 np 10.4 #3
```

NOTE that I added ( `#1` and `#2` and `#3` ) to clarify to output.

Each `route` is in `@L` that you can access them by

all: `@L`
some(first and second): `@L[0,1]`

and if you are willing to see the output in **single-line** not separated line you can add `-l` option to affect on the output separator

So:

```
perl -lne '$s=$.;($e=$s+5) if/route-table.*?$/g && ($rt=$&); push(@L,$_) if $s++<$e && !/(?:route-table|rg)/;if($s==$e){print @L;@L=()}' file
```

has the output:

```
 route testroute p 1.0/24 np 10.4 #1 route route2 p 1.0/24 np 10.4 #1 route route3 p 1.0/24 np 10.4 #1
 route testroute p 1.0/24 np 10.4 #2 route route2 p 1.0/24 np 10.4 #2 route route3 p 1.0/24 np 10.4 #2
 route testroute p 1.0/24 np 10.4 #3 route route2 p 1.0/24 np 10.4 #3 route route3 p 1.0/24 np 10.4 #3
```

If you notice, I stored the result of match `$&` into variable `$rt` and you can use it later, in the second `if` condition. For example for titling your output, like:

```
... print "$rt =>",@L;@L=()}' file
```

it outputs:

```
route-table arlrt2 => ...
route-table arlrt3 => ...
route-table arlrt3 => ...
```

and eventually I am sure you can implement this simple script with [python](/questions/tagged/python)